# When removing an item in a list, I'd like the item to stay in place as it fades out

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

Using **Vue.js** and **Transitions**.

When removing an item from a list, I'd like the item to fade out, but stay in place as it fades out.  I'd also like the item below it to transition up into it's new position.  I haven't been able to find a way to make both of these desired behaviors take place.

```
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

This CSS appears to be needed to make the 'next' item transition into its new location, but appears to also make the 'leaving" item transition up into the top position as it's leaving/fading out.

Removing this CSS makes the item being removed stay in place as it fades away, but then we loose the nice transition of the 'next' item in the list.

The JSFiddle will make this much clearer... https://jsfiddle.net/rprpx/vaq5nzL8/

Thank you.

Comment: Removing the `list-wrap` class on the `transition-group` fixed it for me.

Comment: @YomS. That's perfect! Thank you! That's the answer! .... The flex settings I had on the `transition-group` were making it act that way. And they weren't necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at list transitions at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions

Basically you can just use the example there and remove the `transform: translateY(30px);` part.

I have created this fiddle with the change above, to show the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/suterma/s5zLrfom/